# What unusual effects can taunts come in?

Tags: team-fortress-2

What effects can Unusual Taunts come in? Couldn't find anything on the wiki, and the TF2 wiki hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: Unusual effect taunts?  Is that a thing now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luwwi.jpg) it seems like there's a pretty good number of taunt effects out. Names are taken off of the imgur album I found. All of these can go on any taunt, or at least those dropped off of the new crate, the Audition Reel. At the moment, any unusual taunt is going for stupid amounts of cash/buds, as you can see [here](http://forums.backpack.tf/index.php?/topic/12821-unusual-taunts-on-outpost/).

**Screaming Tiger**
[image: Screaming Tiger]

**'72**
[image: '72]

**Holy Grail**
[image: Holy Grail]

**Skill Gotten Gains**
[image: Skill Gotten Gains]

**Silver Cyclone**
[image: Midnight Whirlwind]

**Midnight Whirlwind**
(not pictured)

**Mega-Strike**
[image: Mega-Strike]

**Showstopper**
[image: Showstopper]

**Fountain of Delight**
[image: Fountain of Delight]